# Anti-derivative of gradient

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a function $f(x,y)$  such that  $\frac{1}{x} \nabla f(x,y)$ is well defined in $[0,1]^2$? (Other than $f(x,y)=c_1 x^ny^m + c_2 ;\ n>1$)

If yes, what it can be?

Thanks

Comment: What about $f(x,y) := x^2y$

Comment: ${1\over x} \nabla f$ will never be defined for $x=0$, but it can be extended for $x=0$ by continuity.

Comment: @lisyarus it can be defined... For example $\frac{1}{x} \cdot x$ is defined, you don't have to extend the function by continuity

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question

Comment: @Thinking No, ${1 \over x} \cdot x$ is *not* defined when $x=0$, since it would equal to ${1 \over 0} \cdot 0$, and ${1 \over 0}$ is not defined.